# Primeng components not updating translations with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, primeng

I am working on an app where we extensively use primeng components. We just implemented multi-language with ngx-translate and everything works fine, without need of reloading, except for the primeng components. These components stay with the former translations until we perform navigation to a different page or a complete reload.

Reloading the whole app is not what we had in mind, and navigation doesn't solve our sidebar menu, which is out of the router outlet and thus doesn't get reloaded on navigation.

We can solve this with a BehaviorSubject that somehow refreshes the whole sidebar menu, but again, we expected something more out-of-the-box from primeng.

Take the following app example that has the same problem:
https://github.com/sudheerj/angular-primeng-ngxtranslate

For instance, if we had the following template:

```
<h1>{{ 'HOME.Summary' | translate }}</h1>
<p-dataTable [value]="employees" [rowStyleClass]="lookupRowStyleClass">
<p-header>{{'List of employees' | translate}}</p-header>
<p-column field="id" header="{{'EmployeeID' | translate}}"></p-column>
<p-column field="firstname" header="{{'FirstName' | translate}}"></p-column>
<p-column field="lastname" header="{{'LastName' | translate}}"></p-column>
<p-column field="description" header="{{'Description' | translate}}"></p-column>
<p-column field="gender" header="{{'Gender' | translate}}"></p-column>
<p-column field="grade" header="{{'Grade' | translate}}"></p-column>
<p-column field="experience" header="{{'Experience' | translate}}"></p-column>
<p-footer>{{'This is a list of employees registered in the last week' | translate}}</p-footer>
</p-dataTable>
```

If I change language by executing:

```
this.translate.use('es');
```

Then only the text in the  tag gets translated, but the p-column headers don't. The p-dataTable only gets its fields translated if I navigate to another place and then navigate back, or if I perform a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Use onLangChange event from Translate Service and get data again.
Ex:

```
this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(event => {
  console.log(event.lang);
  this.yourText = translate.instant('key_from_json');
  //OR
  getYourAjaxDataAgain();
}
```